# Escape characters SQL Server 2008 R2 [%]

Tags: sql, escaping, pivot

I am trying to pivot a resultset, one of the values in the rows which iam comparing against is COutputData_2_Magnesium Stearate [%].  SQL does not seem to like the [%] symbol, i dont have anyway to change the how the name is shown in the result set.  Is there a way I can escape [%] when pivoting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `QUOTENAME` function to get the proper escaping for possible non standard identifiers.

```
SELECT QUOTENAME('COutputData_2_Magnesium Stearate [%]')
```

returns

```
[COutputData_2_Magnesium Stearate [%]]]
```

So use that.

Example

```
WITH T(Id, Val)
     AS (SELECT 1, 'COutputData_2_Magnesium Stearate [%]')
SELECT *
FROM   T PIVOT ( AVG(Id) FOR Val IN ([COutputData_2_Magnesium Stearate [%]]]) ) AS P;
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much. I used the following [COutputData_2_Magnesium Stearate [%]]] and it worked.

Comment: Found another issue. The script runs but returns null
I am using the following method to pivot                                   
max(case when Name = ''[COutputData_2_Best class match]'' then value end) COutputData_2_Best_class_match,
max(case when Name = ''[COutputData_2_Magnesium Stearate [%]]]'' then value end) COutputData_2_Magnesium_Stearate_percentage

The result for both the columns is null?

Comment: @Abe If you have another question ask another question. Though probably you need `case when Name = 'COutputData_2_Best class match ...` as the value itself doesn't contain square brackets.

Comment: Sorry cannot add newline while commenting. Fairly new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Oh Okay. I have added a new question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634555/escape-characters-and-blank-space-when-pivoting-returns-null

Comment: Thanks once again it works if I do the following max(case when Name = ''COutputData_2_Best class match'' then value end) COutputData_2_Best_class_match,
max(case when Name = ''COutputData_2_Magnesium Stearate [%]'' then value end) COutputData_2_Magnesium_Stearate_percentage