# Escape characters [%] and blank space when pivoting returns null

Tags: sql, pivot

Found another issue. The script runs but returns null

I am using the following method to pivot (The quotations are due to the statement being contained in exec statement)

```
max(case when Name = ''[COutputData_2_Best class match]'' then value end) COutputData_2_Best_class_match,
max(case when Name = ''[COutputData_2_Magnesium Stearate [%]]]'' then value end) COutputData_2_Magnesium_Stearate_percentage
```

The result for both the columns is null?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following

```
max(case when Name = ''COutputData_2_Best class match'' then value end) COutputData_2_Best_class_match,
max(case when Name = ''COutputData_2_Magnesium Stearate [%]'' then value end) COutputData_2_Magnesium_Stearate_percentage
```